# setting colnames within a loop sets the names to numbers

Tags: r

I am trying to change the column names of a data frame to stock symbols as I loop through a list of stock symbols and download stock data.

I have a list of stocks that I read in and then loop through. Within the loop, I download the stock data, set the column name, and then merge with another data frame, but when I print the colnames, numbers are set to the column names instead of the stock symbols.

For example, in stocks.txt, I have:

```
JCP
SVM
GSG
```

The r code is as follows:

```
options(digits=4, width=70)
library("zoo")
library(tseries)


# load the data into a zoo object using the zoo function read.csv
source(file="portfolio.r")

# Dowload the stock data of stocks listed in the stocks listing, such as stocks.txt
stocksymbols = read.table("stocks.txt", 
               sep="\t", 
               col.names=c("symbols"), 
               fill=FALSE, 
               strip.white=TRUE)
stocksymbols

prices <- get.hist.quote(instrument="^gspc", start="2013-01-01",
                      end="2013-12-21", quote="AdjClose",
                      provider="yahoo", origin="1970-01-01",
                      compression="d", retclass="zoo")

colnames(prices)[1] <- "GSPC"
for(i in 1:nrow(stocksymbols)) {
    stocksymbol <- stocksymbols[i,]
    con <- url("http://quote.yahoo.com")
    if(!inherits(try(open(con), silent = TRUE), "try-error")) {
      close(con)
      x <- get.hist.quote(instrument=stocksymbol, start="2013-01-01",
                          end="2013-12-21", quote="AdjClose",
                          provider="yahoo", origin="1970-01-01",
                          compression="d", retclass="zoo")
      colnames(x)[1] <- stocksymbol

      prices <- merge(prices, x)

    }
}

colnames(prices)
```

How do I change the column names to stock symbols instead of the numbers.

Comment: Please provide a minimal *reproducible* example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `stocksymbols` is a factor. If you add `stringsAsFactors=F` to your `read.table(...)` call, your code works.

```
stocksymbols = read.table("~/stocks.txt", 
                          sep="\t", 
                          col.names=c("symbols"), 
                          stringsAsFactors=F,    # read as a character vector...
                          fill=FALSE, 
                          strip.white=TRUE)
```